# Select Many in Rx

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Please any one let me know how the `SelectMany` operator in Rx works. I don't know more about this operator in Linq either.

Please explain this with the help of a simple example, and also in what occasion we will use this operator in Rx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869329/rx-enumerableex-for-vs-enumerable-selectmany

Comment: It seems bit complicated.. i am pretty new to the technology. can u provide a simple sample

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`SelectMany` combines projection and flattening into a single step. Suppose you have a number of lists like `{ {1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, { 6, 7 } }` you can use `SelectMany` to flatten it into a single list like: `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`

`SelectMany` in Rx can flatten multiple sequences into one observable (there are actually several overloads).

For a practical example, suppose you have a function `DownloadFile(filename)` which gives you an Observable which produces a value when the file completes downloading. You can now write:

```
string[] files = { "http://.../1", "http://.../2", "http://.../3" };

files.ToObservable()
                 .SelectMany(file => DownloadFile(file))
                 .Take(3)
                 .Subscribe(c => Console.WriteLine("Got " + c) , ()=>  Console.WriteLine("Completed!"));
```

All 3 observables of `DownloadFile` are flattened into one, so you can wait for 3 values to arrive to see that all downloads are completed.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you used SelectMany here in your code, you don't have list of lists -> you didn't get any flatten, I mean, how will the result be different in your code if you just used select?

Comment: With `Select`, you'd end up with an observable of observables.

Comment: Could you explain more? that was not clear for me, I am still new in LINQ and RX

Answer (score 25):

SelectMany is just:

```
source.Select(selector).Merge();
```

In other words, it selects the source input into a stream of Observables, then flattens each Observable into a stream of results.

Answer (score 10):

I found this short video helpful in understanding SelectMany for Rx (and as a more advanced use of marble diagrams): http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/J.Van.Gogh/Reactive-Extensions-API-in-depth-SelectMany